# Java Swing Drawing (Trouble with PaintComponent)

Tags: java, image, swing, paintcomponent

This is my first post in this forum so excuse me in advance if I make a mistake in formatting or posting etiquette here.

I am fairly new to programming in Java Swing and I've been trying to create simple tower defense game for a personal project yet I'm running into trouble with drawing images onto my application. I've looked around in many of the java tutorials both on this forum and on Oracle but I've never been able to find a solution that helped fix this so I'm resorting to asking for myself.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    new DotO();
}

public DotO()
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();             
        }
    });
}

private void createAndShowGUI()
{
    backgroundPanel = new JPanel();
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    loadBackground();  
    setBackground(Color.white);  

    //1. Create the frame.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Defense Of The Origin");

    //2. Optional: What happens when the frame closes?
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //4. Size the frame.
    frame.setSize(SIZEX, SIZEY);

    //5. Show it.
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //3. Add Background Panel
    frame.add(backgroundPanel);  
}

private void loadBackground()  
{  
    String fileName = "resources/Background.jpg";  
    try  
    {  
        URL url = getClass().getResource(fileName);  
        backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(url);  
    }  
    catch(MalformedURLException mue)  
    {  
        System.out.println("url: " + mue.getMessage());  
    }  
    catch(IOException ioe)  
    {  
        System.out.println("read: " + ioe.getMessage());  
    }
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)  
{  
    System.out.println("painted");
    super.paintComponent(g);  
    int w = getWidth();  
    int h = getHeight();
    g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, w, h, this);  
    System.out.println("it's working");
}
```

The frame does open with no trouble at the preferred size but nothing is drawn on the frame. All I see is a gray space and when I put a System.out.print inside the paintComponent method, it doesn't show in the console so I know the application never actually runs the paintComponent method. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you subclass `JPanel?`

Comment: Assuming `DotO` is your panel class, you never add it to the frame, so it never needs to be painted, hence the no-call to `paintComponent`. You only add `backgroundPanel`.

Comment: @Fernando I've tried subclassing the JPanel but the problem I ran into with that was the paintComponent method was inside the subclassed JPanel and I wasn't sure how I could add additional images other than the background image using that way so I tried a different way.

Comment: @peeskillet How would I go about doing that? I'm sorry I'm really confused at the moment. DotO is my main application which extends JPanel and when I try the frame.add(DotO) it throws an error so I'm not certain what you mean.

Thank you both for the responses though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This obviously belongs into a class

```
class DotO extends JPanel { ... }
```

However, in your `createAndShowGUI` method, you are creating a **new** panel and adding this panel to the frame. In this panel, the `paintComponent` method is not overridden.

On the other hand, you are never creating a "visible" instance of `DotO`. You are only creating an instance of `DotO`, but never adding it to a frame or so.

One solution would be to omit the `backgroundPanel`, and instead of

```
frame.add(backgroundPanel);
```

you could call

```
// Add "this" to the panel. "this" is the DotO instance
// where the `paintComponent` method is overridden
frame.add(this);
```

You should consider pulling the GUI creation out of the `DotO` class, and do the creation of the frame in the `main` method, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            createAndShowGUI();             
        }
    });
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() 
{
    //1. Create the frame.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Defense Of The Origin");

    //2. Optional: What happens when the frame closes?
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //4. Size the frame.
    frame.setSize(SIZEX, SIZEY);

    //5. Show it.
    frame.setVisible(true);

    // Here, create an instance of "DotO", and add it to the frame!
    frame.add(new DotO());
}

// In the DotO constructor, only do what has to be done
// specifically for this DotO instance:
public DotO()
{
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    loadBackground();  
    setBackground(Color.white);  
}
```

But that may be considered as a detail now.

---

EDIT in response to the comment:

In order to paint multiple images, you can just load and paint them like the background image (but **after** the background image, for obvious reasons).

One could give many further recommendations here. Although strictly speaking, this is not the purpose of a Question+Answer site, but should be accomplished by reading tutorials and code samples.

So the Q&A purists: Please leave now, some non-answer stuff ahead:

---

I know that Swing is a "sweet poison": With few lines of code, you have your first frame with some image in it. But this does not mean that you dont have to **plan** and **think ahead** when creating a game. You can not just "write more code" and hope that "something nice" will come out.

Thus, I'd recommend you to first think about how the structure of your game should be. Which classes will you have? What should be the responsibility of each class, in terms of *fields* and *methods* that the class will have?

It's certainly not wrong to write "test snippets" for certain functionalities. For example, a test snippet for loading and displaying a background image ;-) But you can not create a game by only writing lots of code from scratch into a single class.

A guideline here occasionally is to describe *in Words* what you want to achieve. As an example (very "compressed", to illustrate the point) :

> I want a tower that has a certain range and can shoot and can be painted on the screen

This can help to *roughly* derive a structure:

- Nouns are Classes
- Adjectives/Attributes are Fields
- Verbs are methods

yielding a class like

```
class Tower {
    float range;
    void shoot() {...}
    void paintInto(Graphics g) {...}
}
```

(This is really only a very rough guideline!)

Additionally, there will be many details to consider. For example, you'll then notice that it might be beneficial to change your `loadBackground()` method into something like a

```
private void loadImage(String fileName)  
{  
    ...
}
```

method that can be called as

```
background = loadImage("resources/Background.jpg");
tower = loadImage("resources/Tower.jpg");
```

But again: These are things that you can learn from tutorials and code samples (and that you'll (hopefully) do automatically sooner or later)

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't believe it was that simple to solve!

Also if you could give a little advice, what would be the best way to go about adding more images than just the background onto the application? For example, if I want to add a tower at a certain x and y position, should I just create a new ImageIcon and put it in the paintComponent method? Thanks again!

Comment: @Platypi Added an "EDIT" section in the answer

Comment: Thank you very very much! I will take all your suggestions into account and greatly appreciate everything!